# wave propagation ( pict)

Tags: wave, propagation

[image]

Can someone explain to me what is a meaning of the starred items in this picture?

Answer (score 4):

The dot signifies a vector out of the page; the cross signifies a vector into the page.

Comment: In other words, it's a common notation used to describe vectors in three dimensions on 2-D drawings.